# IPhone crash reporting framework

Tags: iphone, ios, crash

I wanted to add crash reporting capabilities to my iPhone app. Kind of the type that prompts you to send a crash report the next time the app launches after a crash (I have seen this capability in NYTines iPhone app, but I am sure there must be others apps doing this as well). Is this a 3rd party framework that can be easily included in any app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are alot of these frameworks, a good article about them can be found [here](http://www.jeremyfuller.net/2011/06/the-battle-of-the-ios-crash-reporters/)

However i would suggest using http://www.crittercism.com/

Comment: This framework is not free for use. The basic package doesn't include sending emails as alret

Answer (score 1):

[Crittercism](https://www.crittercism.com/) caters to my needs at present. The support team is good too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [QuincyKit](http://quincykit.net/). Word of caution though - you'll need to redownload the crash reporter framework from the home site - the build that Quincy site has misbehaves on certain Xcode/iOS conbinations.

But server-side installation is a snap, and symbolication infrastructure is easy to set up, too.

Comment: Me too start to use him. But in some case, CrashReporter.framework is older too, where i can find him sources =)